# Jupyter notebook environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

As part of an online course (OpenHPI MOOC) on deep learning / neural networking, it was recommended to set up a Jupyter notebook with Anaconda 3. One should also set up a special environment called deeplearning2020. The following command should be entered in the Anaconda prompt:

```
conda install nb_conda_kernels
ipython kernel install --user --name deeplearning2020 --display-name "Python [conda env:tensorflow]"
```

After some problems at first, it was recommended to also enter the following command in the anaconda prompt:

```
conda install nb_conda_kernels
ipython kernel install --user --name deeplearning2020 --display-name "Python [conda env:deeplearning2020]"
```

But now you can find 3 options under 'New' in the Jupyter Notebook: Python 3, deeplearning2020 and tensorflow. But in the Explorer I only find the folder 'deeplearning2020'  in '/user/anaconda3/envs'. My Computer is running Windows 10 Pro (64bit). 
How do I get rid of the entry tensorflow in the Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Can you share the installation instructions you're following?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm a complete beginner at Jupyter Notebbok
As far as I understand you, you want to know if I understand the two instructions I have entered. The second instruction is clear: It creates an environment called 'deeplearning 2020'. The first statement refers or directs around the statement 'tensorflow' to the environment 'deeplearning2020'.